# Bash script for curl

Tags: bash, curl

I have a following curl command:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@d:\!zip\products.zip" http://example.com/api/v1.0/import/decisions -H "Authorization: Bearer lcl9pZCI6MiwidXNlcl9uYW1lIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJ1c2VybmFtZVnJlYWQiLCJ3cml0ZSJdLCJleHAiOjE1MDI3NTY4NDIsImVtYWlsX2NvbmZpcm1lZCI"
```

Right now I'm able to upload `d:\!zip\products.zip` (I use Git Bash on my Windows 10 machine) file to server.

The problem is that `d:\!zip\` folder contains hundreds of zip files that should be imported to server.

Could you please show the bash script that will get a list of all files in this folder and then subsequently upload them to server using the curl command mentioned above.

Comment: `cd !zip; for f in *.zip; do curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@$f" http://example.com/api/v1.0/import/decisions -H "Authorization: Bearer lcl9pZCI6MiwidXNlcl9uYW1lIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJ1c2VybmFtZVnJlYWQiLCJ3cml0ZSJdLCJleHAiOjE1MDI3NTY4NDIsImVtYWlsX2NvbmZpcm1lZCI"; done`

Comment: Thanks you very much !